# Define a reset object for nested groups within a given form

Tags: json, forms, angularjs

I am creating a form that has nested groups.  I am making it have nested groups because it needs to return a JSON object with nested values.

Example of the JSON I have to return (pseudocode) I can't copy the actual code there is an airgap:

```
{"Treats": [
  {"id": 1, "type" : "softcandy", "expired" : false,
   "CandyBars":{"name":"mars", "weight":"2oz", "price":"1.00"},
   "ChewingGum":{"name":"superbubble", "weight":".05oz", "price":".50"},
   "SaltTaffy":{"name":"goofyLucyTaffy", "weight":"1lb","price":"17.00"}
  ]
}
```

I can't seem to get the ng-model and form id, name variables right in order to have them recognized by say a reset button and subsequently a submit button.

I was trying the reset method something like this:

```
    $scope.Treats = {
        id: "",
        type: "softcandy",
        expired: false,
        CandyBars: {
          name: "",
          weight: "",
          price:  ""
        },
        ChewingGum: {
          name: "",
          weight: "",
          price:  ""
        },
        SaltTaffy: {
          name: "",
          weight: "",
          price:  ""
        }
    };

    var initTreats = angular.copy($scope.Treats);

   $scope.resetTreats = function(){
       $scope.Treats = angular.copy($scope.initTreats);
   }
```

Short snippet from pseudo html.. could take another 30 minutes to put all of the html in here. .hopefully you get the idea..

```
<DIV class="action-view-body form-horizontal css-form" data-ng-form="junkfood" data-novalidate data-role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="id" required>ID: </label>
   <input type="text" id="id" name="id" class="form-control" ng-model="Treats.id"></input>
  </div>
</DIV>
```

however, when I hit reset it only resets values entered into the id, type and expired form variables and it doesn't clear any validation error messages that appear for those fields.  Help!
(Edited.. I did have initTreats as a var .. typo in trying to convert it to pseudo code.. thanks!)

Comment: Can you add the javascript that manipulates these objects? Also as a precaution, itd be best to store initTreats as a local var instead of putting it on the scope for it to be possibly modified.

Comment: It's not java scripts.. these are form groups with ng-model tags that point to the form names.. I'll add that.. or pseudo that lol

Comment: After looking at your JSON, do you really have the candy as siblings to your id and expiration and so on? Or are they in an array?

Comment: I made a quick plunker but cant find any issue. angular.copy is a deep clone so you should be good. http://plnkr.co/edit/qt4dhN33VAlTBPPmbD6Q?p=preview

Comment: The JSON my form has to send to the rest service must be organized exactly as I have shown.. That's how the data comes out when I do a selectcandy.  I am trying to figure out how to end up giving back what they expect when the fields are filled out

Comment: When I hit reset.. the only fields that get reset are id, type and expired.. values entered into say ChewingGum.name are not reset to "".

Comment: Ok, so can you modify the plunker i sent to show your problem? I don't see what could be wrong with it.

Comment: I am modifying it .. made several changes.. it's not fully fleshed out .. but it should be enough to illustrate my issue.. but it doesn't lol

Comment: Time for me to run.. been banging my head against this for 10 hours.. I'm not familiar with plunkit, how do I see your angularjs definition?  I'll check back in the morning..

Comment: Actually, I modified your example so it illustrates my issue.. =)  and as such was able to figure out why mine doesn't work.. the problem is.. list is not part of the JSON.. How would yours look in a JSON representation?

Comment: Youre going to have to fork it and freeze it and provide me with a new link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to anyone who attempted to help me.  Turns out my problem was referencing constraints that weren't defined in the controller in one of my form field definitions.  I commented that reference out.. and now the form resets perfectly.